# HP backlight keyboard not working after installing Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, keyboard, hp, ubuntu-gnome, backlight

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.2 on my HP Envy TouchSmart 15 and, as you may have guessed from the title of this question, my backlit keyboard stopped lighting up.

I am wondering if there is a special driver I need to install to remedy the situation. I tried running `xset led 3` but my keyboard does not light up.

Comment: Good question, but.. *"who loves studying at night with all the lights off"* - FYI that is really bad for your eyes :)

Comment: @AndroidDev I turn off most of the lights in my room except for this warm nightlight I have and I turn my screen brightness really low so that I don't burn my eyes :)

Comment: I used to do the same. Soft light helps not to burn the eyes in those long study sessions. Just make sure you have enough light, too little is bad long-term.

Answer (score 2):

Hit f5. That toggles the HP backlit keyboard.

Comment: Wow! I was trying to use the Fn key with F5 and getting NO results. I literally face-palmed after trying your suggestion. Thank you for the, what should have been blatantly obvious, answer!!

Answer (score 0):

My HP Pavilion laptop has a button (F11 key), with a picture of a keyboard, and rays of light emanating outward. Pressing that button turns on the keyboard backlight.

If someone ends up at "HP backlight keyboard not working ... Ubuntu", this might help.